# Problem accessing ag-grid table data from VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, ag-grid

Is there a way to loop through a javascript ag-grid table row by row from vb.net in code behind.

Comment: Can the code-behind get the data from the same source as AG Grid did?

Comment: The datagrid data is generated on the page via JavaScript.

Comment: Is the page using web forms or MVC?

Comment: I'm using web forms

Comment: You could put the data, perhaps in JSON format, in the value of an `<asp:Hidden>` control. That would be available to the code-behind on call-back events, like clicking a button.